# KafkaProducer and KafkaTransactionManager No Rollback on exception

Tags: transactions, spring-jms, spring-kafka

**Objective**-

To consumer messages from  a (source) MQ queue and publish to

a) another (destination) MQ queue and

b) a Kafka topic within a transaction thus avoiding removal of messages from the source MQ in case of failures in either the MQ or Kafka publication.

**Frameworks used**

Spring boot version - 2.1.5

Spring JMS -5.1.7

Spring Kafka- 2.2.6

Confluent Kafka- 5.3

MQ -9

**Kafka Config**

```
    @Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.kafka")
@Slf4j
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class KafkaConfig {
    /** injected local properties */
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() throws IOException{
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, keySerializer);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, valueSerializer);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, acks);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, retries);
        log.info("Value of transaction id 0 {}",transactionIdPrefix);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG,transactionIdPrefix);
        sslCommonConfigs(props);
        return props;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() throws IOException{
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, keyDeserializer);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, valueDeserializer);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, autoOffsetReset);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, enableAutocommit);
        sslCommonConfigs(props);
        return props;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> sslCommonConfigs(Map<String, Object> props) throws IOException {
        log.info("kafka config {}",this);
        props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);
        props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, specificAvroReader);
        props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SSL");
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, FileUtil.decodeCertFile(trustStoreValue, "kafka_truststore.jks"));
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, trustStorePw);
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE_CONFIG, SslConfigs.DEFAULT_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE); //"JKS"
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, FileUtil.decodeCertFile(keyStoreValue, "kafka_keystore.jks"));
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, keyStorePw);
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEY_PASSWORD_CONFIG, keyStorePw);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory producerFactory() throws IOException {
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory producerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
        producerFactory.setTransactionIdPrefix(this.transactionIdPrefix);
        return producerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, RawPage> ddaKafkaTemplate() throws IOException {
        return new KafkaTemplate<String, RawPage>(producerFactory());
    }
    @Bean
    public KafkaTransactionManager<String,RawPage> kafkaTransactionManager(ProducerFactory<String, RawPage> producerFactory) {
        log.info("producerFactory.transactionCapable() {}",producerFactory.transactionCapable());
        KafkaTransactionManager transactionManager = new KafkaTransactionManager(producerFactory);
        transactionManager.setNestedTransactionAllowed(true);
        transactionManager.setTransactionSynchronization(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.SYNCHRONIZATION_ALWAYS);
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

**ApplicationConfig Class*

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {
    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myMessageFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
    ChainedTransactionManager chainedTransactionManager) {
        log.debug("Connection factory instance as received {} {}",connectionFactory,configurer);
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        factory.setTransactionManager(chainedTransactionManager);
        factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        log.debug("Returning the myMessageFactory factory instance as {}",factory);
        return factory;
    }
    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
        jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(true);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }
    @Bean
    public JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new JmsTransactionManager(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public ChainedKafkaTransactionManager chainedTransactionManager(KafkaTransactionManager kafkaTransactionManager, JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager){
        return new ChainedKafkaTransactionManager(jmsTransactionManager,kafkaTransactionManager );
    }
}
```

**Actual Consumer and publishing code**

```
    @Service
@Slf4j
@Setter
@Getter
public class MyMessageProcessor {
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, Event> kafkaTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @JmsListener(destination = "desintationQueue"
            ,containerFactory = "myMessageFactory")
    public void receiveMessage(TextMessage message){
        try {
            log.info("Received message {}",message.getText());
            send(destinationQueueName,message.getText());
            // build avro event
            publish(evnet);
            // only acknowledge if the message is successfully processed till kafka publication
            message.acknowledge();
        }catch (JMSException|CustomKafkaPublicationException e){
            log.error("Error in consuming the message from sourceSystem {}", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));            
        }
    }
    public void send(String queueName,final String msg) throws RawPagePublicationException{
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(msg)|| StringUtils.isEmpty(queueName)){
            String errorMessage = String.format("Incorrect message and queue details msg %s queueName %s.",msg,queueName);
            log.error(errorMessage);
            throw new CustomKafkaPublicationException(errorMessage);
        }
        log.info("Publishing the message to destination queue {} at time  in millis {}",queueName,System.currentTimeMillis());
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, msg);
        log.info("Published the message to queue {} at time in millis {}",queueName,System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
```

**Main Spring boot class**

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {KafkaAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableJms
@Slf4j
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableRetry
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = 
{JmsHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class, KafkaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MyConsumerApplication {
```

**Error log**

```
    - [enerContainer-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Clearing transaction synchronization
2019-12-08 19:39:49.270 DEBUG 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.connection.JmsTransactionManager   : Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2019-12-08 19:39:49.332 DEBUG 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.connection.JmsTransactionManager   : Created JMS transaction on Session [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession@1a7d298f] from Connection [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection@5d644e4a]
2019-12-08 19:39:49.333 TRACE 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value [org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsResourceHolder@34a4adbe] for key [JMS_RESOURCE_KEY] to thread [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1]
2019-12-08 19:39:49.333 DEBUG 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=SAMP-CON-0] Transition from state READY to IN_TRANSACTION
2019-12-08 19:39:49.333 TRACE 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value [org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaResourceHolder@48a5eda2] for key [org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory@64aad809] to thread [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1]
2019-12-08 19:39:49.333 TRACE 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Initializing transaction synchronization
2019-12-08 19:39:49.333 TRACE 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsResourceHolder@34a4adbe] for key [JMS_RESOURCE_KEY] bound to thread [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1]
2019-12-08 19:39:49.848 DEBUG 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Received message of type [class com.ibm.jms.JMSTextMessage] from consumer [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueReceiver@2826f379] of transactional session [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession@1a7d298f]
2019-12-08 19:39:49.849 DEBUG 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] .s.j.l.a.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter : Processing [org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener$MessagingMessageConverterAdapter$LazyResolutionMessage@53b59c04]
2019-12-08 19:39:49.849  INFO 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] c.d.g.d.c.a.d.c.DDAMessageProcessor      : Received message 1221222112#
2019-12-08 19:39:49.859  INFO 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] c.d.g.d.c.a.d.c.DDAMessageProcessor      : Publishing the message to destination queue DEST_QUEUE at time  in millis 1575833989859
2019-12-08 19:39:49.861 TRACE 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsResourceHolder@34a4adbe] for key [JMS_RESOURCE_KEY] bound to thread [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1]
2019-12-08 19:39:49.861 DEBUG 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] o.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate   : Executing callback on JMS Session: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession@1a7d298f
2019-12-08 19:39:49.875 DEBUG 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] o.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate   : Sending created message: 
  JMSMessage class: jms_text
  JMSType:          null
  JMSDeliveryMode:  2
  JMSDeliveryDelay: 0
  JMSDeliveryTime:  0
  JMSExpiration:    0
  JMSPriority:      4
  JMSMessageID:     null
  JMSTimestamp:     0
  JMSCorrelationID: null
  JMSDestination:   null
  JMSReplyTo:       null
  JMSRedelivered:   false
1221222112#
2019-12-08 19:39:49.902 TRACE 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsResourceHolder@34a4adbe] for key [JMS_RESOURCE_KEY] bound to thread [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1]
2019-12-08 19:39:49.905  INFO 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] c.d.g.d.c.a.d.c.DDAMessageProcessor      : Published the message to queue DEST_QUEUE at time in millis 1575833989905
2019-12-08 19:39:49.997 DEBUG 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] c.d.g.d.c.a.d.c.DDAMessageProcessor      : Publishing message with key 106e096a-4633-49c8-abaa-a8d0bade84d2: value {"content": "1221222112#", "sourceType": "MQ", "sourceLocation": "MINT", "msgType": null, "correlationId": "106e096a-4633-49c8-abaa-a8d0bade84d2", "receivedTs": 1575833989997}
2019-12-08 19:39:49.999 TRACE 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaResourceHolder@48a5eda2] for key [org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory@64aad809] bound to thread [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1]
2019-12-08 19:39:49.999 TRACE 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaResourceHolder@48a5eda2] for key [org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory@64aad809] bound to thread [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1]
2019-12-08 19:39:50.007 TRACE 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=SAMP-CON-0] Requesting metadata update for topic TOPIC-SAMP-DATA.
2019-12-08 19:39:50.170  INFO 37524 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : Cluster ID: O5fhv74bT9KIkV17ia8snQ
2019-12-08 19:39:50.309 ERROR 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] c.d.g.d.c.a.d.c.DDAMessageProcessor      : Error publishing raw page with exception org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Not an enum: null for schema: {"type":"enum","name":"MsgType","namespace":"com.mysample.avro","symbols":["TYPE"]}
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeEnum(GenericDatumWriter.java:218)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter.writeEnum(SpecificDatumWriter.java:61)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:133)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter.writeField(SpecificDatumWriter.java:98)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:195)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter.writeRecord(SpecificDatumWriter.java:83)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:130)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:82)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:72)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:101)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:53)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:65)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:841)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:803)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:444)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:381)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:199)
    at com.mysample.consumer.DDAMessageProcessor.publish(DDAMessageProcessor.java:106)
    at com.mysample.consumer.DDAMessageProcessor.receiveMessage(DDAMessageProcessor.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:736)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:696)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:318)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:245)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1189)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1179)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1076)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
.
2019-12-08 19:39:50.310 ERROR 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] c.d.g.d.c.a.d.c.DDAMessageProcessor      : Error in consuming the message from sourceSystem com.mysample.consumer.exception.CustomKafkaPublicationException: Error publishing raw page with exception org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Not an enum: null for schema: {"type":"enum","name":"MsgType","namespace":"com.mysample.avro","symbols":["TYPE"]}
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeEnum(GenericDatumWriter.java:218)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter.writeEnum(SpecificDatumWriter.java:61)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:133)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter.writeField(SpecificDatumWriter.java:98)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:195)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter.writeRecord(SpecificDatumWriter.java:83)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:130)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:82)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:72)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:101)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:53)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:65)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:841)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:803)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:444)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:381)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:199)
    at com.mysample.consumer.DDAMessageProcessor.publish(DDAMessageProcessor.java:106)
    at com.mysample.consumer.DDAMessageProcessor.receiveMessage(DDAMessageProcessor.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:736)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:696)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:318)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:245)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1189)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1179)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1076)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
.
    at com.mysample.consumer.DDAMessageProcessor.publish(DDAMessageProcessor.java:111)
    at com.mysample.consumer.DDAMessageProcessor.receiveMessage(DDAMessageProcessor.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:736)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:696)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:318)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:245)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1189)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1179)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1076)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2019-12-08 19:39:50.312 TRACE 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] .s.j.l.a.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter : No result object given - no result to handle
2019-12-08 19:39:50.312 TRACE 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsResourceHolder@34a4adbe] for key [JMS_RESOURCE_KEY] bound to thread [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1]
2019-12-08 19:39:50.316 DEBUG 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=SAMP-CON-0] Transition from state IN_TRANSACTION to COMMITTING_TRANSACTION
2019-12-08 19:39:50.317 DEBUG 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=SAMP-CON-0] Enqueuing transactional request (type=EndTxnRequest, transactionalId=SAMP-CON-0, producerId=435000, producerEpoch=39, result=COMMIT)
2019-12-08 19:39:50.317 DEBUG 37524 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=SAMP-CON-0] Not sending EndTxn for completed transaction since no partitions or offsets were successfully added
2019-12-08 19:39:50.317 TRACE 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Clearing transaction synchronization
2019-12-08 19:39:50.317 DEBUG 37524 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=SAMP-CON-0] Transition from state COMMITTING_TRANSACTION to READY
2019-12-08 19:39:50.317 TRACE 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaResourceHolder@48a5eda2] for key [org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory@64aad809] from thread [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1]
2019-12-08 19:39:50.317 DEBUG 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.connection.JmsTransactionManager   : Initiating transaction commit
2019-12-08 19:39:50.317 DEBUG 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.connection.JmsTransactionManager   : Committing JMS transaction on Session [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession@1a7d298f]
2019-12-08 19:39:50.396 TRACE 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsResourceHolder@34a4adbe] for key [JMS_RESOURCE_KEY] from thread [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1]
2019-12-08 19:39:50.411 DEBUG 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.connection.JmsTransactionManager   : Resuming suspended transaction after completion of inner transaction
2019-12-08 19:39:50.412 TRACE 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Initializing transaction synchronization
2019-12-08 19:39:50.412 TRACE 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Initializing transaction synchronization
2019-12-08 19:39:50.412 TRACE 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Clearing transaction synchronization
2019-12-08 19:39:50.412 DEBUG 37524 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.connection.JmsTransactionManager   : Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
```

**Issue**

The Kakfa producer does not rollback transaction thus resulting

1. the destination queue having data which should not be there
2. the source queue does not have the message anymore
3. the kafka topic does not have the message .

**Things tried**

1. Using Throwable vs Exception in rollback
2. Putting the code for publishing to queue and topic into separate classes

How can we test for rollback scenarios to be working for Kafka producer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
at com.mysample.consumer.MyMessageProcessor$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a0eef45f.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:736)
```

I don't see a transaction interceptor in the stack trace, which implies the `@Transactional` is not working - you need `@EnableTransactionManagement` on a `@Configuration` class.

However, you really don't need `@Transactional`, simply inject the `ChainedTransactionManager` into the listener container factory so both transactions are started there.

Comment: Thanks Gary. The main class does have EnableTransactionManagement (i have added it with MyConsumerApplication .Due to some character limitations i had to remove some stacktrace logs earlier and hence i have added the complete stacktrace. Apologies . For interceptor comment, are you referring to only Kafka interceptor as i can see in the logs the below lines for receiveMessage. --2019-12-08 10:58:02.629 TRACE 35476 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [com.mysample.consumer.MyMessageProcessor.receiveMessage]

Comment: You should never edit stack traces in questions; it is misleading. So you do have an interceptor but you have the Jms Tx manager twice; once in the container and once in the chained TM. Try injecting the chained TM into the container factory and removing `@Transational`. Also, since you have the Kafka TM first, you should set its `setTransactionSynchronization()` to `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.SYNCHRONIZATION_ALWAYS`. Also, make sure the consumer has `isolation.level=read_committed`; finally, turn on DEBUG logging for `o.a.k.c.i.TransactionManager`.

Comment: That said, if you put the Chained TM in the container, you should put the JMS TM first because you probably want the JMS tx to rollback if the Kafka commit fails. Set `SYNCHRONIZATION_ALWAYS` on the JMS TM.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I have implemented as suggested to remove Transactional & have the chainedTM in the container. I do see the TransactionManager for producer logged however the behavior is the same(i.e. no rollback by kafkaTM and thus by ChainedTM). For the order of TMs in ChainedTM, i have used JMS first now.

Comment: 2019-12-08 18:49:46.340 TRACE 39972 --- [enerContainer-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Initializing transaction synchronization
 2019-12-08 18:49:46.340 DEBUG 39972 --- [enerContainer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=SAMP-CON-0] **Transition from state IN_TRANSACTION to COMMITTING_TRANSACTION** . Will try some actual debugging with the latest settings it seems somehow the failure in submission is not being recorded as a failure. _When there is a JMS publication failure the message remains on the source queue_

Comment: There is something weird going on; it's not just the Kafka tx that is committed `2019-12-08 18:49:46.305 DEBUG 39972 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.connection.JmsTransactionManager   : Committing JMS transaction on Session [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession@4c770401`] And they are in the wrong order, Kafka should commit (or rollback) first. I suggest debugging in the Chained TM.

Comment: thanks.. i am checking the orders.. **But there is no rollback at all for the Kafka producer . any pointers for that?**  With the error (intenationally added) there should have been a rollback statement from kafkaTM. anyways heading into some real time debugging now that the configuration does not seem to be the problem..

Comment: You need to find the root cause; both transactions are committing instead of rolling back.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `ChainedKafkaTransactionManager` and wire all used transactionmanagers into it:

```
    @Bean
    public ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<String, String> chainedTransactionManager(DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager,
                                                                                    KafkaTransactionManager<String, String> kafkaTransactionManager) {
        return new ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<String, String>(kafkaTransactionManager, dataSourceTransactionManager);
    }
```

In my case the DataSourceTransactionManager has been replaced by the KafkaTransactionManager. Therefore @Transactional stopped working: No more rollback on RuntimeExceptions.

The ChainedTransactionManager works as expected. Just keep in mind that this is no XA Transaction but a simple chained 1-Phase-Commit.